# Transform sklearn dataframe into Pandas dataframe, preserving categorical labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I am importing data using sklearn:

```
from sklearn import datasets
dataset = datasets.fetch_openml('credit-g', version = 'active')
```

sklearn on the fly converts categorical data into numbers.

[image]

Now I want to convert this dataset into Pandas DataFrame:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(dataset.data, columns = dataset.feature_names)
data['class'] = pd.Series(dataset.target)
```

but this command drops all categorical data - they are numbers now.

[image]

What I want is dataframe which will have after conversion original text labels in place of numbers. So, after conversion from sklearn dataframe into pandas dataframe data should look identically as if I simply downloaded this data with command:

```
pd.read_csv("https://www.openml.org/data/get_csv/31/dataset_31_credit-g.arff")
```

[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [`fetch_openml`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.fetch_openml.html#sklearn.datasets.fetch_openml), the returned dictionary contains:

> ```
> [...]
> data : np.array or scipy.sparse.csr_matrix of floats
>     The feature matrix. Categorical features are encoded as ordinals.
> [...]
> categories : dict
>     Maps each categorical feature name to a list of values, such that the value
>     encoded as i is ith in the list.
> [...]
> ```

There is no option to not encode categorical features. As long as you will use `sklearn` to download your dataset, you will have floats and not strings.

However, as the categories are also returned, you can rebuild the "base" dataset with categorical features from that as below (I am not sure it is the fastest solution, nor the more elegant):

```
from sklearn import datasets
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def main():
    dataset = datasets.fetch_openml('credit-g', version = 'active')

    raws = [
        np.take(dataset['categories'][feature], dataset['data'][:,i].astype(int))  # Take string value for categorical features
        if feature in dataset['categories'] else dataset['data'][:,i]  # Else use the floats as is
        for i, feature in enumerate(dataset['feature_names'])
    ]

    data = pd.DataFrame(np.stack(raws, axis=1), columns=dataset.feature_names)
    data['class'] = pd.Series(dataset.target)
    print("Initial dtypes:")
    print(data.dtypes)

    dtypes = {
        f: 'category' if f in dataset['categories'] else 'float'
        for f in dataset['feature_names']
    }
    dtypes['class'] = 'category'
    data = data.astype(dtypes)
    print("\nFirst cast:")
    print(data.dtypes)

    int_cols = [1, 4, 12]
    data.iloc[:, int_cols] = data.iloc[:, int_cols].astype('int64')
    print("\nInt cast:")
    print(data.dtypes)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you! It woks. I have one more question. Now I try to convert types of columns from object type to categorical and numeric types but nothing happens: data.iloc[:,[0,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]] = data.iloc[:,[0,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]].astype('category') data.iloc[:,[1,4,12]] = data.iloc[:,[1,4,12]].astype(float) Columns are still stay object type. And if I try to convert columns 1,4,12 to int64 I get an error.

Comment: @Helios I updated the answer with the cast part. Your error with int is that the string `"6.0"` is an invalid input for the `int()` constructor. However, the float `6.0` is a valid input. So convert all to floats, and then to int. I had no problem with the categories.